# Unable to see the code coverage report after updating the sonarqube server from 6.7 LTS to 6.7.7 LTS

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan

**Sonarqube Server:** 6.7.7 LTS (Upgraded from 6.7 LTS)

**DB:** MySQL

**Env:** EC2, t2.large | Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1088-aws x86_64)

**Projects Run for Analysis:** Java | Spring boot

---

**Actual way of updating:**

1. Upgraded the server in the traditional way. Download the sonarqube
   set-up, paste it in a folder.
2. Stop the old version, copy the configs. Start the server from the new folder
3. Once started, the sonarqube will ask for DB migration tapping on OK, the DB migration completes and sonarqube will become live.

---

**Problem:**

- After the update, I'm not able to see the code coverage for the projects that are run newly.
- This means I was able to see the code coverage for a project and I ran the Jenkins job to update the code coverage. Now, the code coverage is showing 0%.
- I can see locally on my machine that the code coverage is more than 50%. But not on the SonarQube server.

---

**Solutions tried so far:**

- I thought the sonar properties are not set correctly and did some tweaks. - NO HELP
- I thought changing the project key will resolve the problem - NO HELP
- I thought of setting up SonarQube on my local machine and run the analysis - VOILA, CODE COVERAGE WAS SHOWN.
- Just to make sure again, I ran a project which had a Code coverage of about 30% on the EC2 instance (where I'm having the problem) - Code coverage turned to 0%. Ran the same job on my local machine, code coverage showed as 30%

---

I'm unable to find the root cause for this since if it was a DB migration problem, all the projects should have been 0% regardless of the analysis was done prior to server update or later.

Please enlighten me to resolve this problem.

---

*P.s: Do not ask me to check with latest LTS version 7.9 as it does not support MySQL and only PostgreSQL and Oracle are supported.*

Comment: Any issues seen in the log files? Did you check the existance and contents of the coverage file to be used by SonarQube?

Comment: Yes, I checked everywhere. No errors in logs and the jacoco.exec file exists. As mentioned, I did check the same code base with local server and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. Thanks to the active sonarsource community. https://community.sonarsource.com/t/jacoco-code-coverage-is-shown-as-0-after-sonarqube-server-update/13570/2?u=vighnesh_pai

Actually, the latest version of sonarqube will by default install the sonar-jacoco plugin. However, this is missing in sonarqube version 6.7.x. (Not sure why?)

I went to the marketplace and searched for the jacoco plugin, it was not installed. I installed, restarted the server and ran the job. It worked like charm!